# How to structure array data in CockroachDB for maximum performance?

Tags: cockroachdb

CockroachDB does not allow indexing of array fields, which means we must probably work around this limitation using a lookup table. But because only one index can be processed per query (assuming this applies to joins as well), performance would degrade if both sides contained a lot of records (e.g. 100s of millions).

Example:

A fictive table is holding many records of news articles and the hashtags which each article contains. We want to query for both at the same time, e.g. by `article AND hashtags`. As there doesn't seem to be a way to index `hashtags []` (is there really no way?), the query engine would first find matching articles and then iterate these to look for matching hashtags. If many articles match, the walk would fail or be slow.

[image: a fictive table using an array]

Now let's normalize `hashtags []` into a lookup table. We would query data using a `JOIN`. Let's again assume there are 100s of millions of records on either side. I guess the DB engine would either use the array on the left or the array on the right, then again walk the other side without using an index, which would be detrimental for performance, too.

[image: a fictive table structure using a lookup table instead an array]

In reality, there are many more fields on either side that need be queried, but for simplicity, I reduced complexity for this example.

Is there any data structure that I can use, which allows CockroachDB to process both sides of the lookup using the same index, an inverted index structure, whatever can help to improve query performance so there is no walk over an excessive number of records?

*NB: I have not tested this, because I assume performance will be excellent having just a few test records, and will degrade much later when the amount of data grows.*

Comment: Did you read https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/inverted-indexes.html? In recent versions you can even have compound indexes with the last column being the array/JSONB - which is likely useful if you want to query around a given article ID.

Comment: I had seen the `inverted-indexes` document, but I wasn't aware a compound index is possible containing a regular index and an inverted index. This possibly solves my problem well.